# Can storeEval process ajax requests in selenum IDE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, selenium-ide

I am trying to create a dynamic tester which will get the input from a database and compare it to what comes out of the page. Can Selenium IDE do something like that using storeEval?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE is built on JavaScript technology. This tool will not allow you to do what you want.

You will need to upgrade to something more. Consider Selenium WebDriver, together with Java, which allows you to do (almost) anything. Including access to database via JDBC.